# is Ruby 1.9 compatible with rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is possible to use ruby 1.9 with rails 2.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know rails 2.3.5 runs with ruby 1.9.1. However you will need to double check any gems or plugins you want to use with ruby 1.9 to see if they work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://isitruby19.com/) site to see whether or not the gems you're using are 1.9 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

2.3.4 has a unicode conversion issue in activemailer, so make sure you use 2.3.5.  Most mainstream rails gems and plugins are now 1.9.1 compatible.