# Does jruby 1.6.5 compatible with rails 2.3.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Did anyone tried with jruby 1.6.5 to work with rails 2.3.10 or 2.3.x version ?

Answer (score 2):

it sure is and I recommend you go with the latest 1.6 which is **1.6.8**

jruby-1.6.x is ruby 1.8.7 compatible which is "ideal" for rails 2.3.x

try running `jruby -v` you'll get something like:

`jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_32) [linux-i386-java]`

reporting **ruby-1.8.7-p357** compatibility (in --1.8 mode) ...

if you're about to use a Java webserver such as Trinidad (or Warbler) that uses JRuby-Rack as the compatibility layer between Rack/Rails and Servlets be sure to use (~> 1.1.13) **1.1.13.3** it's (backwards) compatible with all JRuby 1.6.x and runs Rails 2.3x (as well).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would just give it a try. JRuby 1.6.5 tries to be complient to Ruby 1.9.x, so the real question could be one of these:

- [is Ruby 1.9 compatible with rails 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148848/is-ruby-1-9-compatible-with-rails-2-3)
- [Is it feasible to use Ruby 1.9 for Rails yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033484/is-it-feasible-to-use-ruby-1-9-for-rails-yet)

I don't remember what you had to to to use Rails 2.3.x, but if should be similar easy to do the following steps (if you have used `rvm` to install JRuby 1.6.5):

- `rvm use jruby1.6.5`
- Start your ruby application.
- Add the gems that are missing by doing: `gem install <missing-gem> -r`

And as the real answer: No, I did not try to use JRuby 1.6.5, because I switched all Rails  apps to 3.x long before JRuby 1.6.5 came out.